# How to create instance method instead of static method from intentions menu

Tags: java, intellij-idea, method-reference

I usually let IntelliJ IDEA create methods for me by writing the method call before it exists, and press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> to open the intentions menu. This is not working good together with streams and method references.

Let's say I have a collection of a class, `SomeClass`, that I want to stream over. Using the procedure explained above, I get to this point:

[image: Method from method reference]

This method reference can be expressed in two ways (which both compile), either as a static method:

```
static class SomeClass {
  public static boolean someProperty(SomeClass someClass) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Or as an instance method:

```
static class SomeClass {
  public boolean someProperty() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, when pressing enter, the static method is rendered. This is rarely what I want. In all my typical use cases, I want to render an instance method:

Can this behaviour be changed in IntelliJ (in my case version 2019.2.3)?

Comment: *just curious* why you want static class instead of static method?

Comment: @emotionlessbananas The class is just static because it is an inner class and I wanted my example to compile when constructing it. It is not relevant to the question. The question is how to render an instance method.

Comment: in that case you can refer with `object` reference like you have declared `someClass`. I was mistaken by thinking that its not an inner class

Comment: you are passing stream of object and then referring it by static reference, which is working as intended.

Comment: The two last code blocks (the static and the non-static metod) are both valid. Both can be referenced by the same method reference (`SomeClass::someProperty`). I want the non-static variant to be rendered, not the static one.

Comment: If you want other way around, then you will have to map it inside constructor like `Stream.of(someClass).map(sc->new SomeClass(sc)).filter(someClass::method)`... because you cannot ignore stream of `someClass` over which you are iterating. You'll have to map to something else to make this work.

Comment: Well,I don't want to code a workaround just to be able to use the intentions menu to render the "correct" code.

Comment: I have a feeling my question isn't getting understood here...

Comment: you are doing something like this. import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class someClass {

 static class SomeClass {
  public boolean someProperty() {
   System.out.println("Some");
   return false;
  }
 }

 public static void main(String a[]) {

  
  SomeClass object = new SomeClass();
  Stream.of(object).filter(SomeClass::someProperty);

 }
}

Comment: May be i am missing the point

Comment: but you are changing the object type form `someClass` to `boolean`, this is what `map` do

Comment: In this specific case I am trying to filter on a property of the class. That's it. How to render this as an instance method instead of as a static method? The same method reference can be used for both of the methods. I have tried to clarify this in the question.

Comment: you are calling it by class name `SomeClass`, try with either object reference or with `new SomeClass().someMethod`

Comment: @emotionlessbananas Sorry, but both of your solutions are entirely different things (Object references cannot be used, what if the stream contains more than one element? And filtering an object by using a new empty object would just be wierd). The way I express my filter (SomeClass::someProprety) is the correct way to use method references in this case. My __one and only__ problem is how to let IntelliJ render the correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour can not be configured. And in my opinion configuration is not needed, IntelliJ IDEA does the wrong thing in your example. I have filed a [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-226888) for this issue, you may want to vote for it.

Comment: Since you have a gold medal in the intellij-idea tag I suppose you know what you are talking about. How do you know this? Are you involved in development of IntelliJ or similar?

Comment: I am indeed a developer working on IntelliJ IDEA, but anybody with a deep familiarity with IntelliJ IDEA could tell you the same.